# What causes a "NullPointerException" error here and how can I fix it?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I was trying to make a simple application just to experiment with Java graphics but I got stuck with this error so I would really appreciate if someone could help me with that. :)

I get the following

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.draw(Main.java:41)
at Main.createGUI(Main.java:36)
at Main.main(Main.java:20)
 Java Result: 1
```

error when I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JPanel panel;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main m = new Main();
    m.setSize(500, 700);
    m.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    m.createGUI();
    m.setVisible(true);




}
private void createGUI() {
    Container window = getContentPane();

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 700));
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    window.add(panel);

    Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
    draw(paper);

}

private void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}
}
```

Can someone tell me how can I fix this and what is the cause of the error?

Thank you!

Comment: NOTE: You can always read the stack trace, which will tell you the exact line where the exception was thrown.  In the case of a NullPointerException, you can look at each object that is _dereferenced_ on the line and figure it out pretty quick.

Comment: The term "dereference" is not present in the JLS and I do not believe it should be used as it may be confusing when coming from other languages that have language-level pointers. (I'm generally okay with *more abstract* terms, but not with *less abstract* terms.)

Answer (score 7):

The `Graphics` object on this line

```
g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

is `null` as you've used `JComponent#getGraphics` *before the* UI was visible. This is why it is always better to do custom painting by overriding the [paintComponent(Graphics)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) of the `JPanel` `panel`. This will guarantee that the `Graphics` `Object` is initialized first before being used.

- [More on Custom Painting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 3):

NEVER, EVER use `getGraphics`.

As you have found, it can return `null`.  It is, at best, a snap shot of the last paint cycle.  Anything you paint to it will be overriden on the next paint cycle.

Painting in Swing is stateless.  That is, on each paint cycle, you required to repaint every thing you want painted.

Take a look at [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for an overview of performing custom painting in Swing

+1 to reimeus

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` is caused by `Graphics g` being null, and you trying to use a `null` object to call one of `Graphics` methods.

If you search, you'll see that `panel.getGraphics()` returning null is a common issue and that there are a few solutions. See: [Any alternative to calling getGraphics() which is returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184913/any-alternative-to-calling-getgraphics-which-is-returning-null)